# Demanding a recount on [vote]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-synonym-process

There seems to be a redundant and meaningless tag [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vote) I don't see why we need this, should we burninate/Mjölnir/spoil our votes... or [vote none of the above](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOwesWn3vU4)

Thanks to @psubsee we also have the tag [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voting) this should be a synonym.

Comment: The search on [tag:vote] also shows questions with [tag:voting] and [tag:polling].  Seems like they all could mean the same thing, or at least the same concept.  If the tag is needed, i think some tag synonyms are probably needed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that makes things even worse IMO, certainly they should all be synonyms at the very least. Thanks will update

Comment: There is also [tag:vote-up-buttons], which is related, but at least is a noun rather than a verb

Comment: @psubsee2003 not even sure why we need to specify the action of a button as a tag to me, why not [order-pizza-button], [feed-the-cat] etc..

Comment: Not disagreeing, wouldn't have mentioned the tag otherwise.  It is probably too specific of a tag, but don't think it is an appropriate synonym of vote.  Probably would be better as a synonym of another tag (like [tag:button], or burninated completely.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I wasn't disagreeing, just commenting so no offence intended. It does seem to be a bit out of control

Comment: "a bit out of control"? It's [totally bonkers!](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new)

Comment: @Braiam I agree there should be a little education about tag creation, already lots of meta questions about burninating irrelevant tags

Comment: Maybe "Demanding a [vote] recount?"

Comment: Get out the [vote]!

Comment: Vote [vote] off the island.

Comment: Hold on can we make sure this won't be hacked by nefarious regimes?! And do we trust the polls?

Comment: Once [vote] is gone, we can say we were de[vote]d to this burninate request.

Comment: @EdChum It's too late for that. [The Russians have taken over StackOverflow](//ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @EdChum: Disagree about [polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polling) tag.  [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) is different than voting and should not be a synonym.

Comment: I also strongly disagree about polling... absolutely legitimate technical term. Let's not get carried away.

Comment: @jdb noted have removed the tag thanks

Comment: The wiki text is also poor - a straight copy of Wikipedia, which is [advised against and unattributed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/222560).

Comment: Instead of directly voting on this, we should vote to elect electors who will then place their votes on this matter.

Comment: @Braiam - I laughed when I saw the tag `torchtext`. Maybe we need one called `torch-tag` Oh wait .. we already have one of those.

Comment: @kjhughes makes sense the polling is separate, however it is being used incorrectly then and probably needs to be cleaned up

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree if the question is referring to vote polling then it should be nuked

Comment: @psubsee2003: Agreed.